# Custom state in drawable selector for AutoCompleteTextView underline applies before any other state even when false

Tags: android, android-custom-view, autocompletetextview, android-selector, android-textinputlayout

I'm using a *TextInputLayout* containing an *AutoCompleteTextView* and I want its underlining to be red when method `TextInputLayout.setError()` is called.

I've created an attribute called `state_error` in val/attrs, a *CustomTextInputLayout* to overwrite `setError()` method and a *CustomAutoCompleteTextView* to add this new state to its states.

And I've defined the selector like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.example.myapp">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_red_border" myapp:state_error="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_gray_yellow_border" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_white_border" />

</selector>
```

In short, when my `customTextInputLayout.setError()` is called, it calls its *CustomAutoCompleteTextView*'s `setErrorState(boolean)`, which changes this state to `true` or `false` (depending on the value received) and call `refreshDrawableState()` change the drawable.

However, the  underlining is shown red from the very beginning and not white, even with the `state_error` field being `false`. How so? The other states don't seem to be working. If the view gets the focus, the line doesn't change to yellow and when it loses it, it goes back to red, instead of white...

Please, refer to the code below if necessary.

**activity_main.xml** (just the relevant piece)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.example.myapp.CustomTextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/et_nom"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <com.example.myapp.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
            android:background="@drawable/my_selector"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/nom"
            android:maxLength="25"
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:nextFocusRight="@+id/et_primer_cognom" />

    </com.example.myapp.CustomTextInputLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**value/attrs.xml**

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="custom_text_input_layout">
        <attr name="state_error" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**CustomTextInputLayout.class**

```
public class CustomTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout{

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setError(CharSequence error) {
        super.setError(error);
        if (getEditText() instanceof CustomAutoCompleteTextView) {
            ((CustomAutoCompleteTextView) getEditText()).setStateError(error != null);
        }
    }
}
```

**CustomAutoCompleteTextView.class**

```
public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    private static final int[] STATE_ERROR = {R.attr.state_error};
    public boolean mStateError = false;


    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    /**Overrides the method to add the state_error attribute to the drawable state set only
     if its value is true.
     */
    @Override
    protected int[] onCreateDrawableState(int extraSpace) {

        final int[] drawableState;

        if (mStateError) {
            drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace + 1);
            mergeDrawableStates(drawableState, STATE_ERROR);
        } else {
            drawableState = super.onCreateDrawableState(extraSpace);
        }

        return drawableState;
    }

    /**Changes the state_error of the view to toggle the red underline drawable on/off.*/
    public void setStateError(boolean stateError) {
        if (mStateError != stateError) {
            this.mStateError = stateError;
            refreshDrawableState();
        }
    }
}
```

When I call `customTextInputLayout.setError()` from the activity, it works fine and the error is set and unset perfectly, but the line is always red even when the field `stateError` in *CustomAutoCompleteTextView* is `false`.

Comment: i replaced `xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/com.example.myapp"` with `xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` and it seems to work

Comment: I've tried both already and none seem to work.

Comment: so it seems that you choose the hard way of decorating background Drawable,  you could make it 3 times easier by creating a custom `Drawable` class

Comment: How so? Explain, please.

Comment: refer to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/pskink/5be676cb88d34dfb6cb5), note sample Drawable implementation (`ErrorDrawable`) and its sample usage for an `EditText editText`